# BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, c++

i was working with invoking C++ Dlls into C# and ran into a problem

C++ function:

```
    int _declspec(dllexport) CompressPacket(unsigned char *buff, int offset, int len);
```

C# function:

```
    [DllImport("HuffCompress.dll")]
            private static extern unsafe int HuffCompress(ref byte[] buff, int offset, int len);

    ...

    private unsafe byte[] CompressPacket(byte[] packet)
    {
        int len = HuffCompress(ref packet, 12, packet.Length-12);
        byte[] compressed = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            compressed[i] = packet[i];
        return compressed;
    }
```

when

`int len = HuffCompress(ref packet, 12, packet.Length-12);`

is run, i get a BadImageFormatException

As the C# editor is the VSC# Express, it doesn't compile 64 bit programs, so i'm unsure to the problem
Any ideas would be great

Comment: It seems to me that there is a naming mismatch.  Your C++ export is called CompressPacket while your C# import is called HuffCompress.

Comment: As David stated it This is typically the exception you get when code is waiting for a 32 (or 64) bit DLL and you are giving it the wrong bitness

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing Platform Target setting in the Express edition is almost certainly your problem.  You'll have to edit your project's .csproj file by hand.  Run notepad.exe and open the .csproj file.  Locate the property group that looks like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

and add this line:

```
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

Repeat for the Release configuration group, just below that.

Your next problem is the name of the function, it is decorated if you compiled it in C++.  Declare it like this:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
 int  __stdcall HuffCompress(unsigned char *buff, int offset, int len);
```

And your C# declaration is wrong, drop the *ref* keyword on the 1st argument.

Comment: Thx, worked
(i think i put in ref for an earlier test and forgot to take it out >.<)

Comment: The x86 trick fixed the BadImageFormatException I was getting with SQLite (system.data.sqlite.org) on Visual C# Express.

Comment: I have the same problem. But adding this line doesn't change anything. The same error occurs. In a x86 console application it was working with no problem and loaded the dll right out of the "/Windows/SysWOW64" folder. When I tried to put it in my big project. I had to put the whole dll filename as string to the dllimports.

Answer (score 1):

The DLL is either corrupt or it is the wrong bitness. 32 and 64 bit modules cannot be mixed.